# Connecting QGIS 2.14.3 to SQL 2012 both on LocalHost or Remote

Tags: qgis, sql-server, plugins

I am working on establishing MSSQL (2012) spatial connection from my QGIS 2.14.3, its giving me an error like:

> (Error opening connection: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired QODBC3: Unable to connect).

Please anyone with solution.

Comment: What operating system are you trying this on?

Comment: window 7 - 64bit

Comment: can you connect with SQL Server Managment Studio?